# How to change user in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

How to switch user in Google Chrome? I made a new user for myself but now I want to put Google Chrome back to how it was, since this isn't my computer.

I tried clicking and double-clicking on 'default profile' but  nothing happened.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cfMwT.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frustratingly, it's not possible from that screen. Instead,

> Click the icon on the top corner of the window or press Ctrl+Shift+M (Mac: ⌘-Shift-M) to select the user. No icon will appear if you only have one user associated with the browser.

per http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824

In my case, the avatar of a ninja.